# Error en R: no se puede ubicar un vector de tamaño 16.9 Gb

Tags: r

Estoy intentando armar una matriz término-documento, para armar una nube de palabras con el siguiente código:

```
corpus = Corpus(VectorSource(enc2utf8(df_tweets_hashtags$hashtags)))

dtm <- TermDocumentMatrix(corpus)

m <- as.matrix(dtm) 

**#Error: no se puede ubicar un vector de tamaño  10.0 Gb**
```

Alguien podría ayudarme?

Gracias!!

Comment: ¿Que sistema operativo estás usando?¿que arquitectura 32/64 bits? ¿Cuanta memoria física tienes disponible?

Answer (score 0):

Tiene que ver con el límite de memoria RAM que R tiene asignado. Puedes cambiarlo con el siguiente código, en el que el argumento `size` debe ser proporcionado en número de MB.

```r
memory.limit(size = 2500)
```

El tamaño tiene como límite la capacidad de RAM de tu PC.

Creo que esto debería hacerse sólo en casos extremos.

Comment: `El tamaño tiene como límite la RAM de tu PC` <-- yo aclararía que a eso es saludable restarle lo que normalmente usa el OS, so pena de terminar dejándolo todo sin memoria y bloqueando el OS mismo. :)